# Embedding an MVC form inside the old master template architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, umbraco

I have an old Umbraco web application which was upgraded to v6 earlier this year.

It uses .NET ascx user controls and your standard .master pages as you'd expect.

I now need to create a brand new page which is essentially a booking form for an event.

I'd like to create it using MVC, as I do everything with MVC nowadays. I don't really want to duplicate the page layout / the frame. Is it possible to embed an MVC partial view inside the old master templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the form in a .cshtml file and then add it as an Umbraco Macro. But the form couldn't use the MVC approach, it would have to be basic inline razor plus conditional statements. Which is fine but limiting. You could of course have the form posting to a controller action too but this get's a little tricky as it takes the form processing out of the page's event cycle.

Otherwise you are asking if you can reference an action in a masterpage, so no not really. I say "not really" because of course you can but it's unnatural and would make the project a nightmare for anyone to undestand of they were to pick it up. There is an article here as to how you might do it tho': http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Also, there is also the Umbraco [MvcBridge package](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/mvcbridge). This was something a lot of devs used prior to being able to build directly in MVC. Essentially you can set up Macros to point to actions etc. but still within the webforms mode.

It's a great half-way house but I'm not sure abut the compatibility with v6.

Comment: Would you recommend just creating a new separate razor Layout page and then create views for that, rather than trying to use razor views inside a master page?  At the moment, I have too many dependencies to migrate everything to MVC.  I can't justify the cost to the client.

Comment: In your case it comes down to time (which in the client's eyes comes down to cost). You want to use mvc/razor but there is already perfectly good functioning site set up in webforms mode. It sucks but the professional thing would be to either continue developing in webforms mode, or start moving to using cshtml macros. I definitely wouldn't recommend creating two separate layout methods because then you'll get an issue when the client wants your MVC functionality to display in the masterpage or vice versa.